# How to access byte array from String which is made up of bytes array?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to save data in byte code format to my MySql db and retrieve it.

Example

```
String s = "String To Byte Array";
```

I am converting it to byte code using base64 library, so it becomes -

"U3RyaW5nIFRvIEJ5dGUgQXJyYXk="

Now I am saving this value in my MySql database in column with data type longtext

After fetching this value from DB I want to convert it in to original format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the base64 back to string. This might help you.

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/codec/decode-base64/

Answer (score 1):

Once you obtained the encoded string from the database, you can obtain an instance of class `Decoder` and decode the string in this way:

```
Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
byte[] bytes = decoder.decode(encoded.getBytes());
String decoded = new String(bytes);
```